# Query on "cp" command

Tags: shell, cp

I have a directory say `~/MyWorks` which contains the following files in it: `a.c, b.c and c.c`

I want to copy the `MyWorks` directory to `~/MyAssignments` such that only the directory `MyWorks` is copied and not the files in it.  How should I best go about this?

Comment: What do you want to happen with the files that currently exist in `MyWorks`?

Comment: BTW, you can use backticks \`like this\` to put bits of code inline in your post, `like this`, so that you don't have line breaks all over the place.

Comment: @SiegeX. First i want to create `MyWorks` directory and after that only i need to copy the files in it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
mkdir ~/MyAssignments/MyWorks
```

Comment: A++++++++ Would Read Again

Comment: To clarify: you're not really "copying" the directory; you just want to end up with a directory with the same name. Since you're going to have to type the name of the directory anyway, just use the "make a directory with this name" command, which is spelled `mkdir`.